# Ajax seems to load more than what I send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to get data via PHP.

Here is Javascript function using Ajax :

```
function searchTruthsByKeyWords(keyWords, alreadyDisplayedResults)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/BDDs/verites/accesseurs_verites.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
            rqt:'lectureParMotsCles',
            motsCles: keyWords,
            resultatsDejaAffiches: alreadyDisplayedResults
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Error in searchTruthsByKeyWords\nStatus : " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the run PHP code :

```
if (isset($_POST['rqt']) && $_POST['rqt'] == 'lectureParMotsCles') {
    ecrireFic(json_encode(array('test' => '0')));
    echo json_encode(array('test' => '0'));
}
```

The function ecrireFic writes in a file {"test":"0"}, which looks (to me and a JSON validator) like a correct JSON.

I get in Firefox the following error :

```
Error in searchTruthsByKeyWords
Status : parsererror 
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 4755 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Did you try JSON.parse(data) on js side? Also, try adding die(); after echoing your data in php.

Comment: Now yes, and it changes nothing.

Comment: can you do console.log(data); console.log(JSON.parse(data)); and share what does the console (Ctrl+Shift+I in your web browser, console tab) have to say about this? please do both before (or instead) the alert you have there.

Comment: It says "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Comment: OK, I've done minor modifications supposed to have no business with the problem and now it works. I unfortunately didn't commit when the problem was there. So I guess I will give no solution. FYI, the problem arose in Opera and Firefox and disappeared in these same 2 browsers.